# Errors while setting up nginx and php fpm

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm trying to install 3 websites on a VPS running centos 6, NGINX, PHP-FPM and WordPress. I followed the instructions shared in this article :https://deliciousbrains.com/hosting-wordpress-yourself-setting-up-sites/ and i created the below configuration file in sites-available directory

```
server {
    server_name 7symptoms.com;

    access_log /var/www/html/7symptoms/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/html/7symptoms/logs/error.log;

    root /var/www/html/7symptoms/public/;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
    }

 location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I tested the files using nginx test command and php-fpm is configured correctly. But when i try to access a simple hello world (hi.php) file on my website 7symptoms.com, i get 502 bad gateway or 404 file not found error. What's the problem with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

You created config in "sites-available", now you should link this fie to "sites-enabled":

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ #please check that in centos this is correct path
ln -s ../sites-available/website_config_file .
```

Next look into log files and check, does your request are entering the correct website.

Next, if you are using nginx + php-fpm the error "502" means that php-fpm is not running or you wrote wrong path to socket. Please check that file exists: /var/run/php-fpm.sock and (using htop, top or ps) does php-fpm process is working.

Next - if you want to have 3 different websites, it is more secure to use 3 different user, and 3 different php-fpm config (for each website), it means there will be also 3 different unix sockets created.

Comment: thanks but i managed to fix the problem by modifying /var/run/php-fpm.sock; line